# Load a .mat file into another file without accesing variable name from .mat file

Tags: matlab, matlab-load

this problem is very annoying. 
The situation is like this, I am having .mat file with only a single variable in it. I am interesting in loading it in another variable without accessing the variable from the file tha  t I am trying to load. 
Right, now I have tried something like this but with no effect:

```
  A=[];
  details=whos(FileName);
  aux=load(FileName,upper(details.name);  
  A=aux.(details.name);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your MAT file has only one variable in it, you can load the whole thing and extract the name you want from there:

```
aux=load(FileName);
names=fieldnames(aux);
A=aux.(names{1});
```

Comment: `assert(numel(names) == 1);`